# Count custom post type based on two meta data

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

I am trying to count my custom post type called 'appointments' that match two meta data values .

The meta data keys are 'location' and 'timestamp'

So in english my query is:
How many appointments are scheduled at Location at Time

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'appointments',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relationship' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'   => 'location',
            'value' => $place //set this somewhere
        ),
        array(
            'key'   => 'timestamp',
            'value' => $time //set this somewhere
        )
    )
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Docs: [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

You have the flexibility to add just about anything else you need to that, for example, `post_status`.

Comment: Thanks - That looks good, but how do I count it? I can run a $c++ in a loop, but I'd rather do it in the query if I can instead

Comment: [`count( $posts )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) and [`setup_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata), respectively. Alternately, you can use `WP_Query` args in `query_posts()`

Comment: $count = $posts->found_posts; // worked for the count